# How to change run/debug configuration in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

[image: When I want to run this particular test, it gives option 'Nosetest EditCompany']

When I right click this particular method to run it, it gives option 'NoseTest EditCompany'. I want that option to be 'Unittest in EditCompany'. Where did this nosetest even come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your Default Test Runner in PyCharm is set to be Nosetests.

You can change it if you go `Settings > Python Integrated Tools > Default test runner` , and choose  `Unittests`.

[image: Default test runner]

Comment: Thanks @afxentios , I did the same you described above but still I see 'Nosetest' when I run the method.

Comment: Probably the Nosetest left in the PyCharm Run Configuration. Try to remove it by going `Run` > `Edit Configurations...` > `Python tests` and check if the Nosetest exists there. If it does exist, remove it and try again to run your unittests.

Comment: Also note that on the same place  you can configure any type of Test Runner you want by clicking the symbol `+` and choosing `Python tests`

Comment: Done! Thanks @afxentios.